# hubConnection.on("ReceiveClientHub", (ReceivePeerData)-> { is not getting called

Tags: c#, android, signalr

FITBSignalRService is running in a Fragment.
hubConnection.send("BroadcastClient", "adad", "adad"); does get called.
so the client does connect, but not calling ReceivePeerData

Java:

```
        package com.example.fireinthebooth;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Binder;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.Looper;
    
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    
    import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection;
    import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionBuilder;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    
    public class FITBSignalRService  {
        private HubConnection mHubConnection;
        private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
        public class PullRequest {
            public String Url;
            public Integer PullRequestId;
            public String Avatar;
            public String Login;
            public String Title;
        }
    
        ArrayList<PullRequest> pullRequests = new ArrayList<PullRequest>();
        public FITBSignalRService(Activity context, String url) throws InterruptedException {
    
        HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder
                .create("https://xxxxx/fitbHub")
                .build();
    
    
            hubConnection.on("ReceiveClientHub", (ReceivePeerData)-> {
                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }, ReceivePeerData.class);
            hubConnection.start()
                    .doOnError(throwable -> {
    //start fail , try again
    //note: the start function need try chach when we use this function
                    })
                    .doOnComplete(() -> {
                        //start complated
                        int i = 0;
                        hubConnection.send("BroadcastClient", "adad", "adad");
                    })
                    .blockingAwait();
    }
    
    static class HubConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<HubConnection, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(HubConnection... hubConnections) {
            HubConnection hubConnection = hubConnections[0];
            try{
                hubConnection.start();
    
            }catch(Exception e){
                int g = 0;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    class ReceivePeerData{
            Object userId;
            Object peerId;
    }
    
    }
```

C#:

```
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

    namespace FireInTheBoothAPI.SignalR
    {
        public class FITBHub :Hub
        {
            public async Task BroadcastClient(string userId, string peerId)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveClientHub", userId, peerId);
            }



        }
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
            using FireInTheBoothAPI.Endpoints;
        using FireInTheBoothAPI.SignalR;

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddSignalR();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.FITB();


        app.MapHub<FITBHub>("/fitbHub");

        app.Run();
```

### UPDATE

Java has this now

```
class ReceivePeerData{
    public String userId;
    public String peerId;
}
```

but the userId and peerId returned to client are null.

and c# has this now:

```
public class FITBHub :Hub
{
    public async Task BroadcastClient(string userId, string peerId)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveClientHub", new ReceivePeerData() { userId = userId, peerId = peerId });
    }



    class ReceivePeerData
    {
        public string userId;
        public string peerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your client is expecting the server to send `ReceivePeerData`, but the server is sending two strings, userId and peerId

Comment: @Brennan: that fixed the problem, now the ReceivePeerData is getting called but im receiving null data

Comment: Try putting `{ get; set; }` on the C# properties